# Parameters on Vimeo Depth Player

Tags: node.js, video, parameters, vimeo, depth

I am using the Vimeo Depth Player (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-depth-player/) for volumetric videos - only for a hobby/out of curiosity - and I'd like to know more about the parameters we use in the video description (such as in this video: https://vimeo.com/279527916) - I searched for it but I wasn't able to find a description for any of the supported parameters.

Does anyone here knows where to find such description?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this JSON config is not publicly documented anywhere right now, except for the source code which parses it.

If you are using Depthkit to do a volumetric capture, they automatically generate this configuration for you so you don't have to worry about what it means.

https://docs.depthkit.tv/docs/the-depthkit-workflow

The point of this config is to mathematically describe how the subject was captured. e.g. How far is the subject from the camera?  Without all of this, you won't be able to properly reconstruct the volumetric capture.